# Why is Xquery giving me an error on my variable? I

Tags: xml, xquery

I am very new to XML and XQUERY and am having a terrible time trying to validate , what is probably incredibly easy code. The validator keeps telling me that I have an unknown function or expression but seems to stop around my variable. Can anyone help? I'm sure this is an incredibly easy question but I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is the XML:

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    </Address>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
        <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
      </Item>
      <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
        <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </PurchaseOrder>
 </PurchaseOrders>
```

my Xquery:

```
for $x in doc/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder
    let $z := $x/Items/Item
    let$n := count($z)
    where $x/Address[@Type = 'Shipping'] order by $x/Name ascending
    return <Orders><Order><Name>{$x/Name}</Name><NoProducts>$n</NoProducts></Order></Orders>
```

Expected output:

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <name>Ellen Adams</name>
    <noProducts>2</noProducts>
  </Order>
 </Orders>
```

What did I do wrong? I know this is basic but I would love to learn!  Thanks!

Comment: `$x` is a PurchaseOrder. It doesn't have a Name, so `$x/Name` is empty.

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly suggest tagging your question with the specific engine you're testing with, and mentioning (somewhere) which version of the XQuery language it supports; my answer is tested against the XQuery 3.0 engine BaseX.

Comment: BTW, in the future, please quote exactly the error you're given rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: Thank you Charles! I thought it was my variable throwing me off but I guess it wasn't. I was testing with BaseX.

Comment: I also didn't paraphrase my error, that was exactly the one they gave me.

Comment: Hmm. BaseX error messages typically have an identifier preceding them, ie. `XPST0017` for "Unknown Function". If using the GUI, you may need to click the run button to have that error message be printed in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to what you did wrong (since the error provided in the question was insufficiently precise, and when running that same query myself, I received an empty result, but also no errors), but I can provide a query that generates the output you expect.

```
declare context item := document {
  <PurchaseOrders>
    <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
      <Address Type="Shipping">
        <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
      </Address>
      <Address Type="Billing">
        <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
      </Address>
      <Items>
        <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
          <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
        </Item>
        <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
          <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </PurchaseOrder>
  </PurchaseOrders>
};

<Orders>{
for $purchaseOrder in /PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder[Address/@Type='Shipping']
    let $shippingAddress := $purchaseOrder/Address[@Type='Shipping']
    let $items := $purchaseOrder/Items/Item
    let $itemCount := count($items)
    order by $shippingAddress/Name ascending
    return <Order>
             <Name>{$shippingAddress/Name}</Name>
             <PONum>{string($purchaseOrder/@PurchaseOrderNumber)}</PONum>
             <NoProducts>{$itemCount}</NoProducts>
           </Order>
}</Orders>
```

Note that whereas previously `$x` pointed to a purchase order, here the key is a shipping address -- important, because otherwise your `$x/Name` found no data.

Comment: Any idea how I might output the @PurchaseOrderNumber also in the <Order></Order>block? Every time I try to output it gives me all of the shipping and billing address information. Do I need another for expression?

Comment: Could you show me what you're trying (that's emitting excess info)?